# Unable to find html table column index or header name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, onkeypress

I am trying to find a column index or header name when my cursor is in QTY input field inside html table in any of the row. Please view screenshot below.

In this image my cursor is in Qty column, when I press enter I am not able to get the header name (QTY) or column index.

[image]

Following is the code to find index which is not working and always resulted zero. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
 $('#table-id').on('keypress', function (ev) {
        debugger
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            var index = $(this).closest("td").index;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Paste the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table-id').on('keypress', function (ev) {
        debugger
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            var index = $(this).closest("td").index;
            var headerName = $('#table-id th').eq(columnIndex).text();

        }
    });
```

.eq() is a jQuery method that allows you to select a specific element from a collection of elements based on its index. hope this helps

Comment: I successfully get header name by writing this line of code.   var headerName = $('#save-stage th').eq('4').text();  Now only issue in getting index when my cursor is in qty column and i press enter. How can I get index correctly? thanks.

Comment: var columnIndex = $(ev.target).closest('td').index();
try this , if you got the answer please mark my answer as solution @RaufAbid :)

Comment: Your code works like a magic :) thanks a ton :) I was struggling from last three days and resolve in a shortest time on stackoverflow.

Comment: glad i could help ! , please tick mark my answer if this resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in the code. Here is the updated code:-

```
$('#table-id').on('keypress', function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.which : '');
    if (keycode == '13') {
       var index = $(this).closest("td").index;
    }
});
```

1. You have "ev" as a parameter in the event handler function parameter, while you are using **event** inside the function. I have updated the parameter from **ev to event**.
2. You are mixing javascript and jquery. In javascript, we can use event.keyCode for getting key code. While, in jQuery, we use event.which for getting key code. I have updated that line.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    const index = $(this).closest('td').index();
    const thText = $(this).closest('table').find('thead th').eq(index).text();
    console.log(index, thText);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1th</th>
      <th>2th</th>
      <th>3th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```